# Random variable with pdf proportional to Normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I don't understand  the step highlighted in green.

[image]

[image]

I know $f_Z(z)= \frac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $ e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$  when $z>-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$

and $0$ elsewhere;

but i'm stuck at this point.

Comment: $$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \text{etc.} & \text{for } x\ge0 \\ {} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.
$$
$$ {} $$
$$
f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \text{etc.} & \text{for } x\ge0, \\ {} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
$$ {} $$
Maybe you could point out to whoever typeset this thing that the second way of doing it above makes sense and the first is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

The term in the denominator just normalizes the pdf of $Z$ such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Z(z) \, dz=\int_\kappa^\infty f_Z(z) \, dz=1$$

is satisfied.